# defining custom sort function on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation where I'd like to sort my data from mongodb defining my own function, based on numbers of occurrences of some words.

for instance, I have this schema:

```
const RecipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Title: { type: String },
  Content: { type: String },
  PublishDate: { type: Date },
});
```

and those values:

```
Title: 'Chocolate Cake',
Title: 'Naked Cake',
Title: 'Fruit Cake',
Title: 'Beef'
```

So, when I query "naked cake", I'd like a result like that

```
Title: 'Naked Cake', // 1, because have the two words
Title: 'Chocolate Cake', // 2 because have just one word
Title: 'Fruit Cake', // 3 because have just one word
// beef has no match word
```

today I have this query function:

```
  Recipe
    .find()
    .where({ Title: GetQueryExpression(value)})
    .sort({ PublishDate: -1 })
    .exec(callback);
```

And the GetQueryExpression function is:

```
function GetQueryExpression(value){
  var terms = value.split(' ');
  var regexString = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++)
      regexString += terms[i] + '|';

  regexString = regexString.substr(0, regexString.length - 2);
  var result = new RegExp(regexString, 'ig');

  return result;
}
```

do someone have some idea how to achieve that sort, couting the words occurrence!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/text-search/) to perform case insensitive text search, it uses tokenizer & stemming algorithm to find text efficiently. You have to define a `text` index and the search is performed on `text` index of the collection :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB");

var RecipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Title: { type: String },
    Content: { type: String },
    PublishDate: { type: Date },
});

RecipeSchema.index({ name: 'text', 'Title': 'text' });

var Recipe = db.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema);

Recipe.find({ $text: { $search: "naked cake" } }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```